# Javascript scroll to div

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have two issues I'm wrestling with at the moment. I'm trying to use javascript to jump to an ID on the page (I like the slow animation JS gives). The javascript I am using though isn't working though. Here's a JS fiddle with what I'm working on:

http://jsfiddle.net/n6H8v/5/

Here is the code(sorry for the long HTML, but had to use it for testing scrolling):

HTML:

```
<section id="thumbs-work">

    <img id="top-cat" src="images/cat.png">

        <p> /* Large amount of text to force scrolling */ </p>
</section>


    <div class="back-to-top back-to-top-left">
        <p><a>
        <span class="top-jump">BACK TO TOP</span><img src="images/cat.png" alt="back to top"></a></p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".top-jump").click(function() {
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#top-cat").offset().top }, 1000);
                return true;
        });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use this http://jsfiddle.net/xAbpf/

Comment: I would recommend against using javascript to scroll the page... just redirect to an ID or anchor tag using the browser's built in link system. Animating the page scroll adds nothing and takes up the user's time.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you didn't load jQuery in JSFiddle. It's in the upper left, under Frameworks & Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I use this script to accomplish what your doing, now the code doesnt match your class names so you would have to change them, but this will scroll to the bottom then back to the top smoothly.
See [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/4ygcf/1/) for more info

```
 $('a').click(function(){
   $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
}, 1500);
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here´s a javascript function that might be helpful:

```
window.smoothScrollTo = (function () {
  var timer, start, factor;

  return function (target, duration) {
    var offset = window.pageYOffset,
        delta  = target - window.pageYOffset; // Y-offset difference
    duration = duration || 500;              // default 1 sec animation
    start = Date.now();                       // get start time
    factor = 0;

    if( timer ) {
      clearInterval(timer); // stop any running animations
    }

        function step() {
          var y;
          factor = (Date.now() - start) / duration; // get interpolation factor
          if( factor >= 1 ) {
            clearInterval(timer); // stop animation
            factor = 1;           // clip to max 1.0
          } 
          y = factor * delta + offset;
          window.scrollBy(0, y - window.pageYOffset);
        }

        timer = setInterval(step, 10);
        //document.getElementById("but").click();
        return timer;
      };
    }());
```